# Missing Unicode Characters In R outputs on Windows 10

Tags: r, unicode, windows-10

I am running R on Windows 10.

I am having troubles displaying Unicode symbols as shapes for points. (I am trying to put an up-arrow into my volcano plots (\u2B06 , ⬆) for points which are way beyond scale). Some work, some don't.
[example](https://www.r-bloggers.com/unicode-symbols-in-r/) Source

```
TestUnicode <- function(start="25a0", end="25ff", ...)
{
  nstart <- as.hexmode(start)
  nend <- as.hexmode(end)
  r <- nstart:nend
  s <- ceiling(sqrt(length(r)))
  par(pty="s")
  plot(c(-1,(s)), c(-1,(s)), type="n", xlab="", ylab="",
       xaxs="i", yaxs="i")
  grid(s+1, s+1, lty=1)
  for(i in seq(r)) {
    try(points(i%%s, i%/%s, pch=-1*r[i],...))
 }
}

TestUnicode()
TestUnicode(9500,9900)
```

[Example output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rDfW.png)

On my system some characters simply appear as empty square boxes.

So far I understand that this is caused by Windows font issues and that it likely happened by the new way Windows 10 is storing fonts.

Most solutions of similar problems I found were sadly for Unix based systems and used:

```
Sys.setlocale( locale="UTF-8" )
```

I assume that is a Unix command as it gives me the following:

```
[1] ""
Warning message:
In Sys.setlocale(locale = "UTF-8") :
  OS reports request to set locale to "UTF-8" cannot be honored
```

I tried a solution using the 'showtext' package, but somehow that doesn't work either, potentially again Windows 10 could be the troublemaker. [(install 'Noto')](https://www.google.com/get/noto/help/install/)

```
    library(showtext)
    font_paths()
[1] "C:\\Windows\\Fonts"
    font_add(family="Noto", regular="NotoSansSymbols-Regular.ttf")
    plot(1,1,pch='⬆',family='Noto')
There were 12 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
    warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : font family not found in Windows font database
```

Does anyone have a solution ?
would appreciate any help <3

Comment: For showtext, you should call showtext_auto() before plotting.